# How to make a div container expandable when the data inside it increases at runtime?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am struggling with this problem for quite some time. I have created a main container inside an html page which further contains 3 containers (left, middle and right). In middle container, there are a number of DIVs which can increase based on the texts submitted by users. 
As the text values are increasing inside middle container, I want each of the containers(main, right, left and middle to increase there size to fit the content. But it is not happening, the posted data is coming out from the containers.

I am using position as absolute for all containers in CSS.

Could you please suggest ways to accomplish it. Which way will be better, a CSS or JavaScript?
Appreciate your help.![Below is the screenshot what I am facing][10]

Guys please look at html code and css below. This is something I want to do. currently I have kept right container as position:relative, hence when the divs inside right container are getting increased the right container is expanding. If I'll keep middle container's position as relative, then it'll expand according to the content inside it.
However, I want it something like, if anyone of the child container(left, middle or right) expands, the main container should also expands. Is there any way to accomplish this using CSS? If not, how to do it using JavaScript and JQuery?

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top:10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.left{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color:red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.middle{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color:blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.right{
  position:relative;
  top:0px;
  width: 300px;
  left:800px;
  background-color:pink;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SampleCSS1.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
  <div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div>
  <div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div>
  <div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div>
  <div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div>
  <div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div>
  <div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div>
  <div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div>
  <div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div><div>div in left</div>
</div>

<div class="middle">
  <div>div in middle</div><div>div in middle</div><div>div in middle</div>
  <div>div in middle</div><div>div in middle</div><div>div in middle</div><div>div    in middle</div><div>div in middle</div>
  <div>div in middle</div><div>div in middle</div><div>div in middle</div><div>div in middle</div><div>div in middle</div>
  <div>div in middle</div><div>div in middle</div><div>div in middle</div><div>div in middle</div><div>div in middle</div>

  </div>

<div class="right">
  <div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div>
  <div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div>
  <div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div>
  <div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div>
  <div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div>
  <div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div>
  <div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div>
  <div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div>
  <div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div>
  <div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div><div>div in right</div>

  </div>

  </div>

  </body>
  </html>

enter code here
```

Comment: Could you add a link? What have you tried?

Comment: How do you change the div content?

Comment: There's a lot of good jQuery plugins for this. Do a quick [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+plugin+multiple+column+height) and pick the one you like.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I was trying to post image of what I am getting but couldn't do so as I don't have much reputation points (new to this site). The idea is like, I have 4 containers, 1- Main container DIV which contains all the 3 child DIV containers, 2-  left DIV container, 3- Middle DIV container, 4- Right DIV container. Users will login and get JSP page as login result where they can submit some messages in textarea. Once they submit the texts, the texts will be added as DIV inside middle container. As the entered texts will increase, size of middle container should increase.

Answer (score 1):

since you use position:absolute the containers will always have a height of 0 (or something like this, depending on the browser).

so if it's possible for you to do it without position:absolute for the main container and for the case that the middle container is always higher than the other containers you could do it like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="sub sub-left"></div>
  <div class="sub sub-right"></div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}
.main {
  width: 760px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.sub {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
.sub-left {
  left: 0;
}
.sub-right {
  right: 0
}
```

when you can't do it without position:absolute for all containers and it needs to work in ie7 you have to do it with javascript.

Comment: Thanks mgrossklaus for your reply. I tried keeping main container's position as absolute and child containers as relative but it was not working. I want the child container to expand according to the content inside it and hence the main container should also increase in size based on the size of child containers. Could you please suggest how to do it with javascript if its not possible with CSS.

Comment: the main container can never have a dynamic height as long as you use position:absolute for it. when you use position:static or position:relative its height will increase.

Comment: I have just added the code for html and css. please have a look and suggest where I am doing mistake

Comment: well, you still use position:absolute for the middle container. look at this: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jayXR/)

but again: this only works when the middle container is always higher than left and right container.

EDIT: question: you want the left and the right container to be as high as the middle container or you simply want every container to be as high as its own content?

for the second case: simply use float:left for left, right, middle container WITHOUT position:absolute and overflow:hidden for the wrapper.

Comment: Yes, I need every child container to be as high as their content and main container should be as high as the largest child container. I can't keep every container as position:relative, as its not working. Right now I am just keeping the middle container as relative assuming that it will be higher than any other child container. But if the right or left container gets bigger than the middle container, then the main container will not fit to the largest container with this setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css tables to make your containers expand in height. For example:

Your wrapper:

```
.wrapper{
    display:table-row;
}
```

Your 3 columns (containers):

```
.container{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

This will ensure that the height of each column will always expand according to the tallest.

Comment: Thanks for your reply otinanai. I'll try this and see if it works. I am away from my servers otherwise could have tried right away...:)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all 3 divs to expand to the same height based on just what is in the middle table I think you will need Jquery to do that.  If you don't care that the left and right divs do not expand with the dynamic data being entered into the middle div then you can simply add overflow to the middle div.

```
#middlediv {
   overflow:hidden;
)
```

You would also need to add overflow to the parent container tag if there is one.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, I do want all the the 3 DIVs to expand if mid DIV expands. However, I'll try this and see how it looks. I have not used jquery so far, I am sure I can accomplish much more using that.